# Objective-c when to release objects

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

```
-(IBAction)registerUpdate:(id)sender {
    HTTPRequest* request = [[HTTPRequest alloc] initWithUrl:@"http://www.yahoo.com" delegate:self];
    [request doRequest];
}
```

The HTTPRequest makes an asynchronous request and calls the onHTTPResponse method in the current class.

My question is do I have to release request? My guess is that I'm supposed to make it an instance variable?

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Data received: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

How would I release that string object, or should I assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You release it with `autorelease`

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Data received: %@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease]]
```